# Simple Javascript for loop hangs browser

Tags: javascript, for-loop, freeze

This Javascript hangs browser when the number of iteration is set to 5. However, if set to 4, it runs normally. What is the problem?

```
var sample = [  
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]; 

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    swapColumn(sample, 0, 1);   

function swapColumn(array, x, y)
{
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        temp = array[i][x];
        array[i][x] = array[i][y];
        array[i][y] = temp; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to use `var` to declare variables

```
var sample = [  
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]; 

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    swapColumn(sample, 0, 1);   

function swapColumn(array, x, y)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var temp = array[i][x];
        array[i][x] = array[i][y];
        array[i][y] = temp; 
    }
}
```

Otherwise they are treated as global variables, and you are actually overwriting `i` everytime you enter `swapColumn`